# AngularJS validation Error after Submitting and data clearing

Tags: angularjs

I have implemented validation system in forms and it working fine.

Here is my form:

```
    <form name='addContactForm'>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="userid">USER ID :</label><br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.userid" class="form-control" name="userid" restrict-input="{type: 'digitsOnly'}" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$dirty && addContactForm.userid.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$error.required"> User is required.</span>
        <span ng-show="addContactForm.userid.$error.number">Invalid userID</span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">NAME :</label><br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.name" class="form-control" name="name" required/>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.name.$dirty && addContactForm.name.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.name.$error.required"> Name is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.name.$error.lettersOnly">Invalid Name</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email :</label> <br>
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" ng-model="formModel.email" ng-pattern="/[\w\d\.\_]+\@[\w\d]+\.[\w]{3}/" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.email.$dirty && addContactForm.email.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.email.$error.required">Email is required.</span>
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.email.$error.pattern">Invalid email address.</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="phone">Phone :</label> <br>
        <input ng-model="formModel.phone" class="form-control" name="phone" restrict-input="{type: 'digitsOnly'}" required>
        <span style="color:red" ng-show="addContactForm.phone.$dirty && addContactForm.phone.$invalid">
            <span ng-show="addContactForm.phone.$error.required"> Phone Number is required.</span>
        </span>
      </div>

      <div class="row justify-content-center">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="addContactForm.$invalid" ng-click="PassDataToDisplyThroughUrl()">Submit</button> <br>
      </div>

    </form>
  </div>
```

Note that, above things are working fine.

my controller is below:

```
app.controller('formCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$http',
function($scope, $location, $http) {
    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.PassDataToDisplyThroughUrl = function() {
        var url = 'display/' + $scope.formModel.userid + '/' + $scope.formModel.name
         + '/' + $scope.formModel.email + '/' + $scope.formModel.phone;
        $location.path(url);
        $http.post('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/contact/', $scope.formModel)
        .then(function(response){
            $scope.successCallBack = 'You have successfully saved your contact';
        }, function(response){
            $scope.errorCallBack = 'Opps! Unable to save your data, please check your network';
        });
    $scope.formModel = {};
    $scope.addContactForm.$setPristine();
    };
}]);
```

After i clicking on submit button -- it clear the form and send to the server. but **the problem is, it shows me the validation error later**

Can anyone fix me this issue?

Comment: Add `$scope.addContactForm.$setPristine();` to clear the form validations. Also, you should set the `$scope.formModel = {}` after you are saving the contact.

Comment: I added this too but no works, you can see my edited snipped please. can i know why it is not working?

Comment: *but the problem is, it shows me the validation error later* Later means?

Comment: I mean, The validation is working fine, now i need, after i submit the form, it should clear the form, and it works but it is showing me validation error after submitting the form too, why?

Comment: I tried to run your code without API call and just after submitting clearing the data and setting the form pristine. It is not showing any validations. You should check if it is breaking when calling API. Check the console for any errors.